# How to add GeoLocation-Permissions in config.xml

Tags: android, cordova, android-permissions, crosswalk

I'd like to set androids permissions to use geolocation in config.xml.

**I don't want to use cordova-plugin-geolocation** which would set these settings as a side-effect because the webviews I am targeting (crosswalk) support GeoLocation out of the box. The Plugin would just be bloatware.

**I don't want to write it directly in AndroidManifest.xml** because I am using `cordova prepare` to prevent having any plattform-specific stuff inside my repository. Everybody is currently able to build the plattforms from scratch without any plattform-specific stuff from our git-repo.

### What I tried

I took a look at cordova-plugin-geolocation to see how they would achieve this.

```
<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

This returns the following in my build-phase

```
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c cordova build android
/Users/sven/.../cordova/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/armv7/debug/xml/config.xml:34: error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
```

### What my next step would be

I am unsure about why the 'rob-from-cordova-plugin-geolocation'-approach does not work, but maybe it would help to just put above into a new plugin? Is it worth a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is "unbound prefix", have you provided a definition for the "android" prefix that you're using in "android:name"?

Looking at cordova-plugin-geolocation plugin.xml you may need to add this to your XML:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

So that the android namespace is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to add permissions (and many other extra configuration actions) in Cordova straight from CLI's config.xml by adding the plugin `cordova-custom-config` to your environment. It will add nothing in your application and consists only in a group of Cordova hooks.

So, only add the XML chuck in your `config.xml` (`<config-file...`), and also add what @SimonPrickett say in his answer.